# JUnit test in nested Kotlin class not found when running gradle test

Tags: gradle, kotlin, junit5

When I specify a test in a nested class in Kotlin as follows ...

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*

class ParentTest
{
    @Nested
    class NestedTest
    {
        @Test
        fun NotFoundTest() {}
    }

    @Test
    fun FoundTest() {}
}
```

... it is not recognized by JUnit when running tests using gradle. Only `FoundTest` is found and ran.

I am using JUnit 5.1 and Kotlin 1.2.30 and Gradle 4.6.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Defining the nested class as [an inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) resolves this issue.

```
class ParentTest
{
    @Nested
    inner class NestedTest
    {
        @Test
        fun InnerTestFound() {}
    }

    @Test
    fun FoundTest() {}
}
```

As [Sam Brannen indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180845/junit-test-in-nested-kotlin-class-not-found-when-running-gradle-test?noredirect=1#comment85426896_49189049), *"by default, a nested class in Kotlin is similar to a `static` class in Java"* and [the JUnit documentation indicates](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested):

> Only non-static nested classes (i.e. inner classes) can serve as
>   @Nested test classes.

Marking the class as `inner` in Kotlin compiles to a non-static Java class.

Comment: @Sevastyan And all your other tests get recognized as expected? What version are you using?

Comment: `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'` and `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'` with Kotlin `1.3.0`

Nested classes are not recognized at all - tests in them don't appear in the list of tests.

Comment: Are you _other_ (non-nested) tests recognized as expected?

Comment: Yes, other top level tests are recognized.

Comment: `Rebuild Project` might be needed after writing `inner` keyword

Comment: I had the same issue but @user949884 was right, I didn't have the correct import. I had import org.junit.Test instead of import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test. After changing the import the tests were found.

Comment: I did all those things (rebuild, import the correct `Test`, add `inner`) but still doesn't find the tests.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested):

> Only non-static nested classes (i.e. inner classes) can serve as `@Nested` test classes.

Thus, you need to make `NestedTest` an `inner` class.

Comment: I did read that, but be aware this is Java documentation. 'static' is not a thing in Kotlin and the reference to 'inner' class is not exactly the same as the 'inner' keyword for [inner classes in kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html). For example, does this mean by default Kotlin classes all compile to static classes? That said, reading this is why I tried specifying the class as (Kotlin) inner orginally, just not certain about the specifics.

Comment: Yes, by default, a _nested_ class in Kotlin is similar to a `static` class in Java.

Comment: Nesting classes in Kotlin acts more like using namespaces - unless explicitly wanted, nothing becomes an inner class with a reference to the outer class. This is actually very good.