# How to write @Nested test classes in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit5

When writing a junit test:

```kotlin
internal class MyTest {
    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested
    class MyInnerClass {

    }
}
```

A warning is displayed by my code editor (IntelliJ)

> Only non-static nested classes can serve as @Nested test classes.

How to write a nested classes in junit tests in kotlin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180845/junit-test-in-nested-kotlin-class-not-found-when-running-gradle-test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit test in nested Kotlin class not found when running gradle test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180845/junit-test-in-nested-kotlin-class-not-found-when-running-gradle-test)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using @Nested classes in kotlin they need the prefix *inner* as only inner classes can be used as nested classes.

> Only non-static nested classes (i.e. inner classes) can serve as
> @Nested test classes.

- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested

Your code should look somewhat like this:

```
internal class MyTest {
    @Nested
    inner class MyInnerClass {
        @Test
        fun customTest() {
           //TODO: do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your code example missing: @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)? if not, it is identical to mine...

Comment: forgot to add *inner* to my class, sorry