# How to write Nested ParametrizedTest with MethodSource in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, junit5, parametrized-testing

I'm learning how to write test in Kotlin with JUnit 5. I like using feature like `@Nested`, `@ParametrizedTest` and `@MethodSource` when I was writing Java. But when I switch to Kotlin, I encounter an issue:

I figured out how to use

- `@Nested` by referring this [JUnit test in nested Kotlin class not found when running gradle test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180845/junit-test-in-nested-kotlin-class-not-found-when-running-gradle-test)
- `@ParametrizedTest` and `@MethodSource` by referring [JUnit 5 for Kotlin Developers - section 4.2](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/junit-5-kotlin)

But when I put this together, I got

> Companion object is not allowed here.

inside the inner class.

---

Test to reproduce the error

```kotlin
internal class SolutionTest {
    @Nested
    inner class NestedTest {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("testCases")
        fun given_input_should_return_expected(input: Int, expected: Int) {
            // assert
        }

        // error in below line
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            fun testCases(): List<Arguments> {
                return emptyList()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to solve this error? So I can use `@Nested`, `@ParametrizedTest` and `@MethodSource` together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind having `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)`, you can then define your MethodSource method just like a normal Kotlin method, without needing a companion object:

```
internal class SolutionTest {
    @Nested
    @TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
    inner class NestedTest {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("testCases")
        fun given_input_should_return_expected(input: Int, expected: Int) {
            // assert
        }

        fun testCases(): List<Arguments> {
            return emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can specify the method by using fully qualified name of the outer class
**`@MethodSource("com.example.SolutionTest#testCases")`**

Here is an example nested test.

```kotlin
package com.example

// imports

internal class SolutionTest {

  @Test
  fun outerTest() {
    // ...
  }

  @Nested
  inner class NestedTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("com.example.SolutionTest#testCases")
    fun given_input_should_return_expected(input: Int, expected: Int) {
      Assertions.assertEquals(input + 2, expected)
    }
  }

  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun testCases(): List<Arguments> {
      return listOf(
          Arguments.of(1, 3),
          Arguments.of(2, 4),
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks nice, but I want to keep `testCases` method inside `NestedTest` scope.

Comment: I would also prefer to keep the arguments close to the test function. In my case the class is small so it is not a big deal but ideally the arguments should be scoped to the same class as the test which uses them.

Comment: As far as I have seen, having constants in inner classes is not possible
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-i-define-constants-in-an-inner-class/14260